# Electron JS. Как можно реализовать обертку над сторонним сайтом?

Tags: javascript, electron

Вопрос про Electron JS. Как можно реализовать обертку над сторонним сайтом с возможностью добавлять свои скрипты в заголовок с реализацией дополнительных функций.

Необходимо реализовать дополнительную логику на стороне стороннего сайта.
Добавить необходимые фичи, окна и уведомления.

Попытка была реализовать плагин для Chrome, и она успешная, но есть некоторые ограничения для различных вещей.
Хотелось бы реализовать это в виде desktop приложения.
Подскажите какие нибудь мысли, как внедрять свои скрипты и необходимые взаимодействия.
Если это было бы свое приложение, то можно было бы реализовать на NW.JS или подобных, здесь же как кажется Electron JS лучше справится с данной задачей, не смотря на то что потребляет больше системных ресурсов.
Спасибо

Comment: Ну а в чём конкретно проблема то? Electron от плагина сильно не отличается, кроме большего количествоа доступов

Comment: Не удается именно подключать скрипты в заголовки, так как там обращение идет на путь file:///
Пробовал поднять вебсервер, но скрипты корректно не удается подключить, консоль ругается на некорректность подключенных скриптов и файлов, возможно что то не так делаю конечно.
С плагином это удается сделать, а вот с Electron'ом не шибко удается.
Натолкните на мысль.
ps. Если бы это был собственный index.html, проблем бы не было, а тут сторонний сайт, и как обертку со своими скриптами сделать в заголовке, ума не приложу